# Global Key Events in C#

Tags: c#, key-events

So I want to make a Key_Down and Key_Up event in C#, so that they execute no matter what is selected/tabbed to. Basically I want to make a global key event. Is there a way I can do this? Am I supposed to put it on a form? Because if so, then my comp has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the form `KeyPreview` property set to `true`. It Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

When KeyPreview property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus.

You can read more about [Form.KeyPreview Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)